# Robot_upstart can't find path in my package

Tags: ros, robot-upstart, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I got a bug using robot_upstart.
I tried the install script with differents packages located in my catkin workspace and I get this :

```
Unable to locate path launch/example_lucos.launch in package teleopRoboteq. Installation aborted.
```

Is my catkin workspace corrupted ?

Thanks

***Edit 26/01/2015:***
I just test with a new ROS instalation. I use a compiled package with catkin_make, roboteq_driver. The launcher and the job were correctly installed.
I tried with my robot description package and robot_upstart doesnt find it for an install. How do you install your robot description package with ROS and, more importantly, where ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224497/robot_upstart-can%27t-find-path-in-my-package/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-19**:
Can you also provide the `rosrun` command you used?

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-01-20**:
Here it is (something like that):

```
rosrun robot_upstart install lucos/launch/lucos.launch --interface p1p1
```

I also try on a new install and I get the same error.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-01-20**:
It seems that there is a conflict between this 2 lines on some of my installations (.bashrc):

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2016-01-20**:
I have problems in robot_upstart too, maybe to write a upstart job to start your roslaunch is better option.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-01-21**:
I have done the same installation (i'm using the two line script to install ROS) on another computer.
I just got the source of "joystick driver" and made a launch that I used with robot_upstart and I didn't get any trouble.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-02**:
@TomSon: please describe your workspace layout and contents for us. Also add how you build it and what files you source (including your `.bashrc`). Issues with your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` would seem to suggest there is something incorrect in your ws setup / interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<s>Your two source lines are not a conflict. In fact, both lines are necessary.</s>

There may be a package name error in your `rosrun` command. What is your package name for the launch file in question? Can you provide the output of `rospack find your_package_name` ?

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-01-20**:
When I use rospack find , I dont find my package (here lucos).

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-20**:
Then it means that you have a problem with your workspace sourcing. Can you post the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` ?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-01-20**:
Only the second `source` command is necessary. The first one should have been done before creating the `catkin_ws` initially. Perhaps that was not done correctly?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-20**:
@joq, it is not a must but [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) states: "This process allows you to install several ROS distributions (e.g. fuerte and groovy) on the same computer and switch between them."

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-20**:
@Akif: no, @joq is correct. You should *never* need to do what @TomSon is doing, provided you created your workspace correctly. The "switching" you refer to is not meant to be *in-place switching*, but rather allows you to source a different `setup.bash` in a new terminal. Not in the same.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-20**:
Although I do not think the problem is related with that, I updated my answer with feedbacks from you and @joq. Sorry for that.

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-01-21**:
@gvdhoorn, so there is indeed an issue with my workspace freshly installed ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-21**:
Well it depends on how you set it up. In principle you only source the *last* workspace in a chain. In this case, I'd say that is your `catkin_ws` (which overlays `/opt/ros/indigo/..`). Sourcing more than one `setup.bash` is not recommended (if supported at all, without additional arguments).

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2016-02-02**:
Everyone! I think I got it. What is your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ? I think it missed one, I will go check on my different installations.